# Download roads network from OpenStreetMap and simplify graph of roads

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I exported the roads network from OpenStreetMap. I took ways, their corresponding nodes and plotted them:
[image: Uprocessed network]

I would like to have this graph simplified, here is my desired output (yellow ellipses are nodes and green lines are edges):
[image: Desired result]

I didn't manage to find a tool (or option) that "makes network smoother"? Of course, an option would be to program the solution by myself, but before doing that I would like to know if I am not trying to re-invent the wheel.

Does anyone know if there is an easy option to obtain that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use Java (or another JVM-based language) there is a tool called [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas) which has [an option called `BigNode`](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/tree/dev/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/atlas/geography/atlas/items/complex/bignode#bignode) which does mostly what you need.

Once you export your OSM data to the Atlas format, you can invoke all the BigNodes in that Atlas and it will group all the nodes at similar intersections for you and provide navigable in/out paths through each.